# reading zip file from s3 bucket using scala spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

i am **trying to fetch and read text files in a zip file** uploaded on aws s3 bucket

code i tried

```
var ZipFileList = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(/path/);

   var unit =  ZipFileList.flatMap {
        case (zipFilePath, zipContent) =>
          {
          val zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipContent.open())

          val zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()
          println(zipEntry.getName)
          }
      }
```

but it gives an error **unit required traversableOnce**

```
 val files = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(/path/))
    files.flatMap({case (name, content) =>
      unzip(content) //gives error "type mismatch; found : Unit required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]" 
    })
```

is there any other way to read file contents inside a zip file ...
zip file contains .json files and i want to achieve is to read and parse all those files

Answer (score 0):

you aren't actually returning the data in the unzip() command, are you? I think that's part of the problem

Comment: not an area I've any experienced...you'll have to do your own online research there I'm afraid

Comment: Well i got one working  way ,by first downloading the zip File then unzipping it locally and then uploading unzipped using spark job..:)